# Loading .txt files fast into an pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, dask

This is the code i am using at the moment it is working fine and does exactly what i want.

```
df_list = []

for file_name in reversed (os.listdir(path)):
        df_small = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file_name), delimiter='\t', decimal='.', skiprows=6)
        df_small = df_small.dropna(subset=[df_small.columns[6]])
        df_list.append(df_small)

df= pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

I am looking for ways to make it faster. At the moment i am loading around 5000 files in the df, the resulting df has around 140 000 rows for this process i need around 20 seconds.
(The files all of have the same layout and around the same size ca.7 kb)

So are there any ways to make it even faster?
Would it make sense to switch to something like dask to read the data even faster or is that unnessary

Comment: Do you need the contents of all files at once in the dataframe?

Comment: What takes the time, the loading, parsing or final concat?

Comment: Update the question to include relevant [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) timing measurements.

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating through the files. if the read or load is what’s taking up the majority of the time, this iterative approach is your bottleneck.

you can use a dask bag to distribute the file paths and load them across however many cores you have available.

Answer (score 0):

The files are small enough that it's probably better to use regular processes and just refactor the code:

```py
def read_f(path):
    df_small = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter='\t', decimal='.', skiprows=6)
    df_small = df_small.dropna(subset=[df_small.columns[6]])
    return df_small

files = (os.path.join(path, file_name) for file_name in os.listdir(path))
df = pd.concat((read_f(path) for path in files), ignore_index=True)
```